# Toolbar to insert HTML tags while editing content

Tags: input-formats

This very site features a neat toolbar just over the textareas in forms, where clicking on "B", for instance, will spawn `**strong text**`, abstracting away the need to know Markdown.

Is there a way to do the exact same thing with, for instance, filtered HTML, or another text format based on HTML, on my Drupal site? I find that WYSIWYG editors tend to bloat the actual code and I want my users to get used to seeing HTML tags, but for the moment they can't be bothered with typing the markup in themselves.

Answer (score 1):

After asking on `#drupal` on `irc.freenode.org`, I was looking for the [BUEditor module](https://www.drupal.org/project/bueditor) that does just that, specifically looking at its native support for HTML tags:

[Screenshot (using BBCode)](https://www.drupal.org/files/images/bueditor-screenshot_0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be using "Markdown" filters.

https://www.drupal.org/project/markdown

More info:

http://cms.about.com/od/drupal-modules/a/Write-Faster-In-Drupal-With-The-Markdown-Module.htm

Comment: My question was about the toolbox JSing markup tags into the textarea, not about the specific markup language (I needed it for HTML). See my answer.